# Python gdata Spreadsheet - save data to cell in SpreadsheetsListFeed

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata

I'm using a `SpreadsheetsListFeed` to read data from a Google Spreadsheet.

The sheet contains a table of customer data, including **firstname**, **lastname**, **email**, **phone**, etc. The column headers are in the top row of the sheet, and the data is in the subsequent rows. I figured a `SpreadsheetsListFeed` would be the best option since the data is in a tabular format.

However, now I need to use the python app to generate a **customerid** for each customer, and write it to the spreadsheet (only if it doesn't already exist in the sheet). I'm wondering if there is a way to do this through the `SpreadsheetsListFeed` or if I need to use a `SpreadsheetCellsFeed` and calculate the row/column values based on the existing `SpreadsheetsListFeed`.

The documentation for the python `gdata` library is a little sparse, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this, but maybe it will be helpful to you? It looks like a good example: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/spreadsheets/spreadsheetExample.py

Comment: Thanks - I should have included that link in my original question. As well as this one: https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.spreadsheet.service.html - Under `UpdateRow` it says: `If you want to add additional information to a row, it is often easier to change the values in entry.custom, then use the Put method instead of UpdateRow. This UpdateRow method will replace the contents of the row with new_row_data - it will change all columns not just the columns specified in the new_row_data dict.` - but I don't know what `Put` method they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the reason why I wrote a small [wrapper lib](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet) for the spreadsheet API. It lets you work with a spreadsheet like you would with a dict.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar :-)